# How is the voltage supply and peak-to-peak voltage of a rectifier found in this example?

Tags: voltage, frequency, rectifier

I'm struggling with rectifier calculations, and below is an example my teacher uploaded in my blackboard. How did he find the frequency of the voltage supply and what is the calculation of the peak rectifier voltage?

From what I thought, you need V<sub>rms</sub> x 1.414 = V<sub>p</sub>, or am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With his calculations, you have the peak voltage already given (20) and the diode drop (0.7) so to get the 18.6V, it is just 20 - (2*0.7). That is shown in his workings. In a full wave rectifier, only 2 of the diodes are conducting at any time, which is why you use 2*0.7, which gives us the result of 18.6V.

You are correct in saying that to find a peak voltage, you can take the RMS and times by 1.414, but in this case it isn't needed as Vpeak is already given (pre-rectifier). This is the first method of finding peak voltage from a sine wave, so that may be where you were confused. But if you are given an RMS voltage in another question, you can indeed use that method to find the peak.

The only thing he hasn't shown is how he got the 50Hz. If you have 20sin(100*pi*t), that is also the same as 20sin(wt), and w=2*pi*f.

Knowing this, we can say 100 is 2*f. 100/2 = 50Hz

If you were unsure where the 100Hz comes from after the rectification, take a look at this graph:

[image]

This is because when the voltage is rectified, the 'negative' side of the wave is 'rectified', resulting in what is essentially a waveform with double the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

A sine wave is expressed in the form Vp*sin(wt)V   where Vp is the peak of the signal(source voltage) and w(omega) is the angular frequency of the that signal and is measured in radians/sec.

the equation that converts a frequency in Hz(hertz) to radians/sec is as follows.

w = 2*pi*f    where f is the frequency measured in Hz

You can modify this equation to get f in terms of w like this f = w/(2*pi)

From the example we have V(in) = 20sin(100*pi*t)V comparing this with Vp*sin(wt)V we obtain the following data.

w = 100*pi

Using the equation mentioned earlier f = 100*pi/(2*pi) the pi cancels and we get 100/2 = 50Hz this is how we get the source frequency

Again comparing the two equations as before we obtain Vp = 20V so the peak voltage of the source is 20V.

to get the output peak voltage we use the following statement:"At any time only two of the four diodes conduct and each one of them(the conducting diodes) drops 0.7 or the threshold voltage given in the example".

to get the output peak we subtract 2*0.7V from the input peak(which is 20V) then Vp(out) = Vp(in)-2*0.7 = 18.6V

Comment: Can you break down this wall of text?

Comment: What a perfect explanation, Thank you very very much!!!